# Moving Item In Observable Collection resets moved item to default values

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listview that contains Comboboxes, a textbox, and a check box. I can add multiple rows, and each time a row is added you get a new row in the list view that contains all 5 of those items. I have a default prepended to the beginning of each of the Comboboxes to prompt the user to select a value from the dropdownlist that it is bound to. The problem is when I try to reorder the rows the move event resets all the values to their default values, clears out the textbox and unchecks the check box.

```
public ObservableCollection<RemovePunctuationRules> PunctuationRules
    {
        get
        {
            return _punctuationRules ?? (_punctuationRules = new ObservableCollection<RemovePunctuationRules>());
        }
        set
        {
            _punctuationRules = value;
        }
    }
private void MenuItemMoveUp_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedIndex = ListView.SelectedIndex;

        if (ListView.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            var itemToMoveUp = PunctuationRules[selectedIndex];
            PunctuationRules.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
            PunctuationRules.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, itemToMoveUp);
            ListView.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add your xaml as well,

Comment: If you put a break point on the Insert, do the properties of `itemToMoveUp` actually change? You could also set a break point in one of its property setters to see if that is being called at any point.

Comment: You might find that `ObservableCollection.Move` is more predictable.

Comment: The problem seems to be that in the XAML I have SelectedIndex set to 0 for when the row is added it sets the comboxes default to 0. If I removed the selected index then I'm able to select a value and move them around without a problem. Problem is when I go to add the rows without the SelectedIndex Set my comboboxes never default